# Connecting to MongoDB Atlas from .Net Core API in Docker container experiences a timeout

Tags: .net, docker, mongodb-atlas

I created an .Net Core API that connected to MongoDB Atlas. Outside of a Docker container, it works perfectly fine. But when I put it in a container, everything else works (including connecting to other cloud resources) but Atlas isn't responding. Atlas is set to allow connections from any source.

The Docker container I'm using is a Windows one (because I'm also including a .Net Framework API too).

Is there some change that needs to be made to Docker to allow it to connect?